# How do I post file to Apache Solr using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, apache, solr

I am kind of asking about best practice here, since I've looked everywhere but can't find any. I'm creating a Solr-based application using NodeJS, particularly [solr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-client) to connect to the Solr. My application is supossed to be able to receive files in multiple kind of formats (from json, xml, csv, etc, which is possible in Solr) and I am using NodeJS for that.

On terminal I can use command like `bin/solr post -c core-name path_to_file` to post any kind of format readable by Solr, but I have some trouble doing that in Javascript. The following code just doesn't work.

```
client.add(thisData, function(err, obj){
    if(err){
        console.log("Failed add file");
        console.log(err.stack);
        // throw err;
    }else{
        // console.log(obj);
        console.log("Successful");
    }
});

client.commit(function(err, res){
     if(err){
         console.log(err);
     }
     if(res){
         console.log(res);
     }
});
```

As a note, thisData is a variable containing the file content that I have obtained using fileSystem. I don't understand why I can post any kind of file format from terminal, but can't do the same from programming thing. Is it not allowed in Solr?

Some friends suggested me to convert all the file contents (from xls, csv, json, etc) to json then send the json to Solr. It works, but I realize that it's so much works. I have to use a lot of nodejs packages to convert those files and I don't find them really efficient. I have been looking for the best way to do this on github but seems like I found nothing to reference to. Can someone give me some hints? I am sorry if I am not being really clear, I will explain more if you need me to.

Comment: Which URL are you posting to? To extract content from a rich file through Apache Tika, the usual way to do that is to post to `update/extract` and submit the file as a regular file POST.  As far as I can tell there wasn't any direct support in `solr-client` for submitting to the extract request handler, but any HTTP client should be able to help.

Comment: The url to post is something entered by user. So the end user is suposed to be able to provide a url containing data to post to Solr. I have also just found out about no direct support in solr-client for files other than json and csv. Is the http client you're talking about is [this] (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JSON+Request+API)? So you mean I use that code in my NodeJS, right? I've never tried something like that before, is it the best practice there is? Thanks.

Comment: You can use any HTTP client available for Node, but the endpoint for Tika is described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika